# How can I set up search filter functionality on a gallery with JQuery? It needs to hide results not matching real time key entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-gallery, searchbar

I am creating a gallery with a search filter function. The search filter is supposed to filter out the displaying thumbnails per key entered. The search is based on the `img` caption stored in `title` tags. For example, if I type 'la' every image with matching text in the `title` should appear until I enter 'lake'.

My script has variables that store the search term and image titles (not sure if I got this right). Then, I added a function with a variable for the search term. The search terms show up in real-time per key entry in my log.

I added `console.log($img === $searchTerm);` to make sure my thinking is on the right track and that the search entry will return true, but it keeps returning false. It may not be the most ideal/efficient method, but my thinking is that logging the correct results should come before manipulating the DOM.

I'd rather not use a plugin, other than the lightbox plugin I am already using. I want to understand how to add the search function and how it works.

**HTML Example**

```
<div class="gallery" id="gallery">
            <div class="imageContainer" title="someText.">
                <a href="photos/01.jpg" title="someText" alt="someIMG"class="images">
                    <img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="someIMG" class="thumbnails">
                </a>
            </div>
      </div>
```

**Script Example**

```
    const $searchBar = $(`#searchForm > input`);
    let $img = $(`.imageContainer > a[title]`);

    $searchBar.on('keyup', function(event) {
        const $searchTerm = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
        const $imgList = $img.toArray();

        console.log($searchTerm);
        console.log($img === $searchTerm);

    });
```

Thanks again for any input!

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
const $searchBar = $('#searchForm > input');
const $img = $('.imageContainer > a[title]');

$searchBar.on('keyup', function(event) {

    var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); 
    //I removed the $ as it is not a jQuery object, but it doesn't really matter

    $img.show(); //show them all first

    $img.each(function() { //no need for $imgList as it is already an array

        var title = $(this).attr('title').toLowerCase(); 

        if (!title.includes(searchTerm)) { //do you need to support IE? use indexOf if so
            $(this).hide(); //hide if not a match
        }

    });

});
```

If you need to support IE, something like this would work instead of the `includes` function.

```
if (title.indexOf(searchTerm)) {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Update 2:

Here is the updated code to deal with people just entering spaces and not text, plus with the IE fix:

```
const $searchBar = $('#searchForm > input');
const $img = $('.imageContainer > a[title]');

$searchBar.on('keyup', function(event) {

    var searchTerm = $.trim($(this).val().toLowerCase()); //we trim this to remove whitespace

    $img.show();

    if (searchTerm) {

    $img.each(function() { 

        var title = $.trim($(this).attr('title').toLowerCase()); //and we trim this too

        if (title.indexOf(searchTerm)) {
            $(this).hide(); 
        }

    });

    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been at this for hours. It works perfect! I really appreciate the answer and the help, and especially the notes.

Comment: I had an issue with it having the elements hidden on backspace so I modified it to `(!title.includes(searchTerm) && searchTerm !== null)`, which worked. Is this a preferred method or is this bad code? 
Also, regarding indexOf(), I need some clarification. I tried `(!title.includes(searchTerm) || !title.indexOf(searchTerm) &&...)` and `(...|| !title.indexOf($imgList) &&...)`. The second script ran in Chrome, but not IE, so I tried `(...|| !title.indexOf($img) &&...)`. If I understand correctly, I'm checking the search against all of the `title` tags, right?
Thanks again!

Comment: Everything hides when you backspace? It shouldn't happen because we display everything first and only hide the non-matches. Can you tell me a bit more about what is happening?

I also added some extra code for the indexOf function. You're not comparing it to the array, but instead the title of each array, if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

We take the search input value, then we compare it to the title, then we hide that doesn't match by the letter (No need to type all the letters of the word(title)):

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  let term = e.target.value;
  let term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

  if(term) {
    toggleDisplay('none')    
    let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(let i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
       if(elements[i].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(term)) {
         elements[i].closest('.card').style.display = 'block';
       }
    }
  }
  else {
    toggleDisplay('inline-block')
  }
});

function toggleDisplay(display) {
  let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
  for(let i=0; i< cards.length; i++){
    cards[i].style.display = display;
  }
}
```

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {.container {max-width: 540px;}}
@media (min-width: 768px) {.container {max-width: 760px;}}
@media (min-width: 992px) {.container {max-width: 960px;}}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {.container {max-width: 1190px;}}

.form-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.search-input {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
}

.card {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 1%;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.card:hover .card-ul {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.card-ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s;

}

.card-li {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-container">
        <form id="search-form">
            <input type="text" id="search" class="search-input">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <a href="">
              <div class="img-div">
                  <img class="img" src="...">
                  <div class="desc">
                      <ul class="card-ul">
                          <li class="card-li black">Black</li>
                          <li class="card-li yellow">Yellow</li>
                          <li class="card-li jwhite">White</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>text</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                  <p>text</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
          <a href="">
              <div class="img-div">
                  <img class="img" src="...">
                  <div class="desc">
                      <ul class="card-ul">
                          <li class="card-li black">Red</li>
                          <li class="card-li yellow">Green</li>
                          <li class="card-li jwhite">White</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>text</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                  <p>text</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
          <a href="">
              <div class="img-div">
                  <img class="img" src="...">
                  <div class="desc">
                      <ul class="card-ul">
                          <li class="card-li black">Denim</li>
                          <li class="card-li yellow">Amaranth</li>
                          <li class="card-li jwhite">Celadon</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>text</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                  <p>text</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
          <a href="">
              <div class="img-div">
                  <img class="img" src="...">
                  <div class="desc">
                      <ul class="card-ul">
                          <li class="card-li black">Brown</li>
                          <li class="card-li yellow">Capri</li>
                          <li class="card-li jwhite">Camel</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>text</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                  <p>text</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
          <a href="">
              <div class="img-div">
                  <img class="img" src="...">
                  <div class="desc">
                      <ul class="card-ul">
                          <li class="card-li black">Brown</li>
                          <li class="card-li yellow">Blond</li>
                          <li class="card-li jwhite">Blue</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>text</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                  <p>text</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
          <a href="">
              <div class="img-div">
                  <img class="img" src="...">
                  <div class="desc">
                      <ul class="card-ul">
                          <li class="card-li black">Beaver</li>
                          <li class="card-li yellow">Aqua</li>
                          <li class="card-li jwhite">Pink</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>text</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                  <p>text</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
          <a href="">
              <div class="img-div">
                  <img class="img" src="...">
                  <div class="desc">
                      <ul class="card-ul">
                          <li class="card-li black">Amber</li>
                          <li class="card-li yellow">Apricot</li>
                          <li class="card-li jwhite">Amethyst</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>text</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                  <p>text</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good idea using vanilla Javascript. If we are bringing CSS into it, maybe a class toggle would be better than changing the display style. Nice ideas though.